# Regex - Remove date and time from a list in python using regex

Tags: python, regex

Regex - I have a list of strings in that one of the string is date and time but i want remove dates field and empty spaces from the list.

This is my input list:

```
['Hello how are you',
'',
'fine',
'',
'had you break fast',
'',
'I had   1',
'',
'2016-06-11   5:06 PM',
'',
'Are you going to school today ',
'No!',
'',
'What? You gave ',
'I given money.',
'',
'2',
'',
'money   2',
'',
'2016-06-11   5:08 PM',
'']
```

desired output format:List After Processing

```
['Hello how are you',
'fine',
'had you break fast',
'I had   1',
'Are you going to school today ',
'No!',
'What? You gave ',
'I given money.',
'2',
'money   2']
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
dirty_list = ['Hello how are you', '', 'fine', '', 'had you break fast', '', 'I had   1', '', '2016-06-11   5:06 PM', '', 'Are you going to school today ', 'No!', '', 'What? You gave ', 'I given money.', '', '2', '', 'money   2', '', '2016-06-11   5:08 PM', '']

clean_list= []
for i in dirty_list:
    if i != '' and not re.search('\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s+\d{1,2}\:\d{2}.*',i):
        clean_list.append(i)
```

This should do it. It basically ignores the empty items and date formats in the list.

**Output:**

```
print(clean_list)
['Hello how are you', 'fine', 'had you break fast', 'I had   1', 'Are you going to school today ', 'No!', 'What? You gave ', 'I given money.', '2', 'money   2']
```